Problema com autorização de API FETCH
Estou tentando conectar a uma API porém estou esbarrando no erro de autorização, não consigo identificar o que está errado, a chave está correta e a url também. se alguém puder me ajudar fico grato.
Segue código js:


async function buscarVagas() {
    try {
        const buscaVaga = await fetch("https://www.teste.com.br/areacolaborador/vagas", {
            method: "GET",
            headers: {
                "Authorization": "Basic 12a29c56d7051b7fdaee5ca2fc0036ea"
            }
        });

        if (!buscaVaga.ok) {
            throw new Error(`Erro na requisição: ${buscaVaga.status}`);
        }

        const vagas = await buscaVaga.json(); 
        console.log(vagas);
        
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Erro ao buscar vagas:", error);
    }
}

buscarVagas();



O retorno de todos os "endpoints" é no formato "JSON" composto no primeiro nivel de um vetor de duas posições: "status" e "data" sendo:
1 "status" => "success" ou "error";
2 "data" => podendo ser conforme o caso:
2.1 "string" : mensagem correspondente ao erro ocorrido;
2.2 "object" : correspondente ao registro obtido da base de dados referente ao identificador informado - "primarykey" (#id);
2.3 "array" : vetor contendo os registros requeridos de uma tabela da base de dados no formato de objeto conforme parametros opcionais informados:
2.3.1 'limit' : limite de registros a serem obtidos de uma tabela da base de dados;
2.3.2 'offset' : quantidade de registros a serem desconsiderados a partir do inicio de uma tabela da base de dados;
2.3.3 'order' : campo da tabela a ser utilizado na ordenação;
2.3.4 'direction' : ascendente ou descendente respectivamente "asc" ou "desc";
2.3.5 'filters' : matriz contendo os parametros a serem aplicados como filtro na seleção dos registros de uma tabela. Ex.: "[ ['active', '=', 1] ]";

Esta pergunta já foi postada faz pouco tempo e lá já foram fornecidas as orientações relevantes. Desta forma, o espaço de comentários foi desativado aqui para evitar descentralização de informações (mas continua disponível na postagem original, se restaurada - é naquela postagem que eventuais melhorias podem ser feitas para reavaliação).
